# When will the Javascript "for...of" loop be implemented in Chrome Chrome?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, for-loop, language-features

I just coded a function using the [Javascript `for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), assuming it had been implemented in Chrome (as in Firefox 13).. It has not.

Does anyone know where i can find out if, and when it is scheduled for implementation?

Comment: Is this really off topic?

Comment: Install coffee script and use it today :) `for key, value of object` http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#loops

Comment: i feel looping over values is something i should be able to do without additional frameworks like CoffeeScript (or jQuery etc..)

Comment: lol, this is one function that will not besupported on all browsers for a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong minute

Comment: @Lloyd I agree, mostly. But in plain widely supported JS, `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { var item = arr[i]; }` is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When ES6 lands. `for ... of` is a [proposed feature](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aiterators) of ES6.

ES6 should land in 2014 if you're lucky.

As for what you should use today, try

```
array.forEach(function (value) {
    ...
});
```

Or

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
    value = object[key];
    ...

});
```

Comment: And I'm sure IE8 support will be close behind...

Comment: your post started me on a research expedition which led to me finding this post, giving me some idea of implementation progress in the Chrominium project https://plus.google.com/113127438179392830442/posts/T615Md5JPQG

Comment: and fyi, i'm using array.forEach instead - you can tell i don't care about IE support ;)

Comment: @Lloyd note using the ES5-shim it's easy to emulate forEach in IE6

Comment: Yeah - thanks. But i am not targetting IE at all, hence the use of for...of in the first place. Thanks for the input - the question correctly, now i think about, has been voted "off topic".